# How to fix a single image inside all other images in android

Tags: android, image, android-layout, android-xml, android-custom-view

After taking all images from gallery i have to put a google drive image on every images.I already listed all images inside views from my gallery.Now what i need is that hardcore a google drive icon image on the left most corner inside all images.The google drive image should be very small as compared to the other images.Any help will be highly appreciated....
  Here is the Code for listing images from gallery

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    protected Cursor mCursor;
    protected int columnIndex;
    protected GridView mGridView;
    protected ImageAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_photo_gallery);

        // Get all the images on phone

        String[] projection = {
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID,
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID
        };

        mCursor = getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                projection,
                null,
                null,
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID + " DESC"
        );

        columnIndex = mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(projection[0]);

     // Get the GridView layout
        mGridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        mAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
        mGridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context mContext;

        public ImageAdapter(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mCursor.getCount();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        // Convert DP to PX

        public int dpToPx(int dps) {
            final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
            int pixels = (int) (dps * scale + 0.5f);

            return pixels;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imageView;
            int imageID = 0;

            // Want the width/height of the items
            // to be 120dp
            int wPixel = dpToPx(120);
            int hPixel = dpToPx(120);

            // Move cursor to current position
            mCursor.moveToPosition(position);
            // Get the current value for the requested column
            imageID = mCursor.getInt(columnIndex);

            if (convertView == null) {
                // If convertView is null then inflate the appropriate layout file
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.conversation_item, null);
            }
            else {

            }

            imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

            // Set height and width constraints for the image view
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(wPixel, hPixel));

            // Set the content of the image based on the provided URI
            imageView.setImageURI(
                    Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "" + imageID)
            );

            // Image should be cropped towards the center
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

            // Set Padding for images
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);

            // Crop the image to fit within its padding
            imageView.setCropToPadding(true);

            return convertView;
        }


    }
```

conversation_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

activity_photo_gallery.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Advance thanks....

Comment: In your `conversation_item.xml` set two imageViews both aligned to top & left make the GDrive image smaller than the other image. You can hardcode your GDrive image source - as you are not going to change it.

Comment: @Skynet i changed my layout as you mentioned.But how to fix it using  adapter?

Comment: Are you providing any functionality to your gdrive image? You need to takecare of recycling of views if you plan to provide a smooth user experience. Read up on recycling views.

Comment: Please be clear when you say "fix it"

Comment: sorry for any problem occurs,i am a beginner...

Comment: no other functionalities.I just need to add a hardcored image(drive)to all other images that i am listed

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `FrameLayout` as the root for  `conversation_item.xml` instead of `LinearLayout`. In a FrameLayout the children are drawn on top of each other.

Or you can align the drive image to the left and bottom and set the size appropriately.

Comment: okay inside the layout i added it.But how to fix it using adapter?Can you please help me i am a beginner to android

Comment: what do you mean by fixing using adapter?

Comment: My image appeared below to all gallery images.my objective is to put drive image inside all images that i am listed...

Comment: You're supposed to change the row item xml i.e `conversation_item.xml` and did you use a FrameLayout?

Comment: No,i aligned the drive image to the left and bottom

Comment: For aligning you used a RelativeLayout right?  Much easier if you use a frame layout..

Comment: Linear layout won't work. As the name suggests it will arrange it's children linearly